# trying to use schema in separate model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What is the correct way to use schema in mongoose and nodeJs,
For example I have a User, Schema A and Schema B, A is embedded in B and B into the User

```
A = module.exports= new Schema({
    _id : false,
    name: { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' }
});

B = module.exports= new Schema({
    _id : false,
    name:    { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' },
    b1 :    [A],
    b2 : [A]
});

module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
  id:           ObjectId,
  firstName:    { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' },
  lastName:     { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' },
  email:        { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.', unique: true },
  password:     { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' },    
  b:       [B]
}));
```

so when a User registers I create a new model

```
var user = new models.User({
    firstName:  req.body.firstName,
    lastName:   req.body.lastName,
    email:      req.body.email,
    password:   hash,
  });
  user.save(function(err) {}
```

Can I create the User like this or do i have to add in `a=[], b=[]` or can i add those fields in at a later time?

Then I am having trouble actually using the Schema in nodeJS if I try export them as models I get an error in my models, So whats working is creating an object A

```
Var a ={
    name:"name"
};
models.User.findOneAndUpdate(
    user.email,
    {$push: {"b.a":a}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

but as far as my schema for A and B goes it is dead code,I'm not using it at all, I'm new to mongo and Mongoose and also node so its a learning exercise for myself so any comments about if I am going the right way in doing this, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to add `a` and `b` at the time when you insert the model to db. You can update it later. That's up to you. To export schemas you should do something like var A =  new Schema({..}) and export it like module.exports.schemas = { A: A, B: B }

Comment: How do i access the schema in the node app, will i have to declare it as a model, this is what i declare on the top of my models                                                                                             `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;` then atop my node app I use `var models = require('../models');`

Comment: If you did what i suggested then you can access schemas like `var schemas = require('../models').schemas;` the variable schemas would be object with A and B schema.

Comment: Regarding the *dead code* the thing is that if you create new user and add schema B to it using new B(...) then it's running validation so it's not exactly dead. But if your schema A is this simple then you can define B simply like this `var schemaB = new Schema('...,b1 : [{ name: {type: String,...}}], b2....);

Comment: thanks alot, the problem was(after I implemented your suggestion) I wasn't sure how to use module.exports.schemas in the node app, but you have set me straight here and i got it working.